# Agree to continue tick box isn't preventing continue

Tags: javascript, html

The last couple of days I've been tackling the issue of preventing a user from moving forward, unless they click on the tick box to agree to the terms. However, the button is allowing them to continue even if they do not click the box. Any thoughts on why?

```
<form action="form.php">
  <script>
      var cb = document.getElementById("cb"),
      button = document.getElementById("button");
      button.disabled = true;
      cb.onclick = function(){
        if(cb.checked checked){
          button.disabled = false;
        }
        else{
          button.disabled = true;
        }
      };
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="checkbox">
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#FFFFFF">I Have Read And
  Agree To The Terms And Conditions<br>
  (check the box if you agree and want to continue)
  </font>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="CONTINUE" name="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: because you have an error `if(cb.checked checked){` Any good linter in an IDE would have pointed out this problem. use your developer tools. The error should have been visible when you clicked the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for this solution here it is.

```
<form action="form.php">
  <script>
    let submitBtn = document.querySelector("button");
    document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function(){
      if(this.checked){
        submitBtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
      }
    });
  </script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="tick" onchange="document.getElementById('terms').disabled = !this.checked;" />
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#FFFFFF">
    I Have Read And Agree To The Terms And Conditions<br>(check the box if you agree and want to continue)
  </font>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="button" name="terms" id="terms" disabled>
    CONTINUE
  </button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the conditional statement in the cb.onclick function. You have two checked keywords, but only one is needed.

```
var cb = 
document.getElementById("cb"),
button = 
document.getElementById("button");
button.disabled = true;
cb.onclick = function(){
if(cb.checked){
  button.disabled = false;
}
else{
  button.disabled = true;
}
 };
```